# Issue with "w" to output and a loop in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an issue with the program i'm currently writing.

Here's the code:

```
def main():

    print ("This program let you create your own HTML-page,\nwith the necessary tags allready included")

    t = ("<!DOCTYPE html>", "<html>", " <head>", " </head>", "<body>", "</html>") #Spaces for the indentation in the HTML-code.

    menu = input("Press 1 to enter the file name for the html-page\nPress 2 to enter title for the HTML-page\nPress 3 to start entering code in body ") 

    while True:
        if menu == "1":
            name = input("Enter the name for your HTML-page: ") 
            #with open(name + ".html", 'w') as doc: 
            #Here is the first problem, indenterror if uncommented, otherwise elif gets syntax error. 
            #And this is crucial to get the code into the HTML-document.
            #The error without (with open(name + ".html", 'w') as doc:) will be "global name "doc" is not defined".
            menu = input("Press 2 to enter title for the HTML-page\nPress 3 to start entering code in body ")
        elif menu == "2":
            print (t[0], file=doc) #<!DOCTYPE html>
            print (t[1], file=doc) #<html>
            print (t[2], file=doc) #<head>
            title = input("Enter your title here: ")
            doc.write(title)
            print (t[3], file=doc) #</head>
            menu = input("Press 3 to start entering code in body ")
        elif menu == "3":
            print(t[4], file=doc) #<body>
            code = input("Type </body> to finish your html-page and to close the program.\nEnter your code for body below:\n")
            doc.write('{0}\n'.format(code)) #For newline to get the HTML-code cleaner.
            while code != "</body>":
                code = input("")   
                doc.write('{0}\n'.format(code)) 
            if code == "</body>":
                print ("Congratulations! You have successfully created your own HTML-page by using this python program.")
                print (t[5], file=doc) #</html> 
                #somewhere in the loop above is the second error, I want the </body> to end the program,
                #but it loops line 25 (code = input("Type </body> to finish your html-page and to close the program.\nEnter your code for body below:\n"))


main ()
```

Now to the issues. As you can see I'm trying to write a menu for the user to choose from 3 different tasks. Everything they do is supposed to output to a .html document.

I have commented my problems in the code as you can see.

I can't figure out how to get the `with open(name + ".html", 'w') as doc:` without the indentation for elif getting messed up, or I simply get an syntax error for elif.

The second problem is my loop at the end. I want the  command to exit the program as it also output the correct ending code for the .html document, but it loops `code = input("Type </body> to finish your html-page and to close the program.\nEnter your code for body below:\n")` and I can't figure that out aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():

    (...)
    while True:
        if menu == "1":
            name = input("Enter the name for your HTML-page: ")
            doc = open(name + ".html", 'w')
            menu = input("Press 2 to enter title for the HTML-page\nPress 3 to start entering code in body ")

    (...)
    doc.close()


main ()
```

You can open a file like so: `doc = open(name + ".html", 'w')`, but don't forget to close it when you're done with it, like so `doc.close()`.

Comment: Or use a `with` statement at the first place, so it will auto-close.

Comment: @glglgl Well, he was having indentation errors, so I thought he'd want to do it the old fashioned way. But yes, `with` is much better. Also, it would be a problem to do that, since his code is structured in a weird way.

Comment: Oomph. I saw your answer without really reading the question. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @glglgl noise? what noise? thanks for taking the time to read my answer! :D

Comment: :-) I'd upvote, but my daily limit is reached. If I'll remember it, I'll do so tomorrow...

Comment: @glglgl lol, I don't think an upvote will work on me today either, i've reached my cap :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple file-opening function. Of course, it needs to be tweaked for your specific needs. The "with" statement itself will close the file.

```
def cat(openfile): #Emulates the cat command used in the Unix shell#
    with open(openfile) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        return ''.join(lines)
```

If you want to write to a file, use this function.

```
def write2file(openfile, WRITE): #openfile = filename to open #WRITE = the string you want to write to file
    with open(openfile, 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(WRITE))
```

To append/add text to a file:

```
def add2file(openfile, add):
    with open(openfile, 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(add))
```